# Limit supremum and limit infimum of a given recursive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Define a sequence of function $\{a_n\}$ as follows: $a_1=1$ and for $n\ge 1$,
$$a_{n+1}=(-1)^n \frac 12 \left(|a_n|+\frac{2}{|a_n|}\right).$$
Then which are correct ?

(A) $\limsup a_n=\sqrt 2$.

(B) $\liminf a_n=-\infty$.

(C) $\lim a_n=\sqrt 2$.

(D) $\sup a_n=\sqrt 2$.

By writting the terms $a_1, a_2, a_3, \cdots$ I can't get anything conclusive.

Clearly there are two subsequences :

$a_{2n}=-\frac 12 (a_{2n-1}+\frac{2}{a_{2n-1}})$

and $a_{2n+1}=\frac 12 (a_{2n}+\frac{2}{a_{2n}})$.

If we assume that, these two subsequences converge say $l_1$ and $l_2$ respectively then we get,

$l_1=-\frac 12 (l_2+2/l_2)$ and $l_2=\frac 12 (l_1+2/l_1)$. Evaluating, we get, $l_1^2+l_2^2=-4$ which is absurd !

How can I solve this probelem ? Any hint. please?

Comment: “Clearly there are two subsequences” No, your formulas do not describe subsequences. Which subsequences do you think they describe?

Answer (score 2):

Let $b_n=2^{-1/2}|a_n|.$ Then $$b_{n+1}={1\over 2}(b_n+b_n^{-1}),\quad b_1=2^{-1/2}$$ By AM-GM inequality for non equal numbers we get  $b_{n+1}> 1,$ hence $b_n> 1$ for $n\ge 2.$ Next $$b_{n+1}-b_n={1\over 2}(b_n^{-1}-b_n)\le 0$$ Therefore the sequence $b_n$ is nonincreasing and bounded below by $1.$. Hence it is convergent to a limit $b\ge 1,$ which satisfies $2b=b+b^{-1}. $ Thus $b=1.$ As $a_{2n}=-2^{1/2}b_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}=2^{1/2}b_{2n+1}$ we conclude that $(A)$ is correct. The condition $(D)$ is not satisfied as $\sup a_n=a_3={17\over 12}.$

Comment: @Cesareo Thanks. I have mixed up the signs.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence does not converge. From the recurrence relation it is immediate that all even terms are non-negative, while all odd terms are non-positive. Thus if there is a limit, the limit can only be $0$, which can not happen since the summand $1/|a_n|$ will blow up then.

To find $\limsup$, it suffices to look at even terms, which is actually the sequence obtained by solving $x^2-2=0$ with the Newton method and initial value $x_0=1$. A standard theory of the Newton method says if $f$ (which is $x^2-2$ here) is in $C^2$, has a simple root in $[a,b]$, $f'$ has no root in $[a,b]$, and $x_0$ is close enough to the root (in this case $x_0>1/2$ suffices), then the sequence converges to the root (which is $\sqrt2$ here).

Therefore the sub-sequence of even terms has a limit $\sqrt2$, thus its limsup necessarily equals $\sqrt 2$. The same approach shows $\liminf$ equals  the limit of the sub-sequence of odd terms, which is $-\sqrt2$

Answer (score 1):

Set $b_n=|a_n|$. Then $b_n\to\sqrt{2}$.
To see this, observe that $b_n$ is decreasing, for $n\ge 2$, and lower bounded by $\sqrt{2}$, and hence convergent, and its limit $x$ satisfies the equation $x=\frac{1}{2}(x+2/x)$.

Clearly, $a_{2n}=b_{2n}$ and $a_{2n-1}=-b_{2n-1}$. Therefore, $\{a_n\}$ possesses two and only subsequential limits, namely $\pm\sqrt{2}$.

Hence, only $(A)$ is correct.

Comment: In your second paragraph, a sign is missing.